# How can one Collapse multiple rows of data in POWERQUERY without using a pivot

Tags: powerquery

I have raised a question on this forum, about how to collapse multiple rows of cell values, whose identity numbers , that identify  students records spilled across a table..The previous method had some performance issues.i do not what to use pivoting because, some of these dataset are data imported from the web,pivot will remove nulls values. These nulls are data to be filled later The Column date is sorted in descending order, so that the latest records is kept while the previous records are discarded. This like remove duplicates and keep the latest records.I have this query solved before buh the solutions, had some performance issues –                            see the challenge:
https://ibb.co/zH2RXRz                                This is what i want:https://ibb.co/98HMCJj

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks you are trying to find the most recent row for each ID, based on the Date column

If so, just group the data

```
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"PriorStepNameHere", {"ID"}, {{"data", each Table.FirstN(Table.Sort(_,{{"Date", Order.Descending}}),1), type table}})
```

then use arrows on top of the new column and expand the extra columns

[image]

sample code for image above:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type datetime}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, {{"data", each Table.FirstN(Table.Sort(_,{{"Date", Order.Descending}}),1), type table}}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Date", "Something", "Something2", "Something3"}, {"Date", "Something", "Something2", "Something3"})
in  #"Expanded data"
```

this is a version that does a "Fill up" into latest date for all columns except ID and Date. Sample code for image below

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type datetime}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, {
   {"data", each 
        Table.FirstN(
            Table.FillUp(
                Table.Sort(_,{{"Date", Order.Descending}}),
                List.Difference( Table.ColumnNames(_),{"ID","Date"}  )
            )
        ,1)
        , type table}
        }),
    #"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Something1", "Something2", "Something3"}, {"Something1", "Something2", "Something3"})
in #"Expanded data"
```

[image]

Comment: This is not working... Even after replacing  nulls with  zero. This has been huge challenge

Comment: Trying using the above example , you discover, that it doesnt work......How can one fill up and fill down the nulls so that every records matching the unique id  is arranged accordingly

Comment: On the off chance that you are looking to do a fill up into the latest date I updated the code.  Beyond that I am not willing to re-type all the numbers in your graphic image to see if my code works with your example. Feel free to get help from others on this one,  this is my last update to the thread

Comment: @horseyride.Anyway thank you,buh doesnt  fix the issue. This is a data coming from the web. An instructor who send a score of a students as zeros.Since that student was absent.               how can this zero values or probably Nulls values replace a  number greater than zero.This could be a powerquery engine faults.....Thank you